# error while loading shared libraries ardrone

Tags: ros, libraries, ardrone, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I needed to pass to Ubuntu 64 bit in order not to have problems with the package ar_track_alvar. I was working with the ardrone_autonomy package, which did work fine until i was on 32 bit. Now, when i launch the node, i get the following error:

fuerte_workspace/ardrone_autonomy/bin/ardrone_driver: error while loading shared libraries: libimage_transport.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

and the process dies.
Any idea to how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57533/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-ardrone/) by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-07-20**:
did u fix it by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use the correct binaries compiled for the architecture on which you are running.

If you're using debian packages make sure you have the right apt sources setup. If you're compiling it yourself from source, you need to clean your workspace and rebuild everything when you change to a new computer with a different architecture.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1